# Python Cx_oracle: executemany throws a TypeError

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I want to use the *executemany* method from *Cx_Oracle* to upload a list of dictionaries to my database. If I use the method it throws an error *expecting string or bytes object* or *expecting date or datetime*. I know that it means there might be an issue with the types of my data but here's where it gets tricky. If I cut my list into small bits I'm able to pin down that an error appears when I run the method for the following dictionaries, i.e.:

```
def send_data(connection , rows):
    try:
        print((rows[23:25]))
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.executemany("""insert into debtors(bankruptID,category,lastname,firstname,patronymicname,fullname,inn,snils,ogrn,region,address,birthdate,birthplace,guid,uploadBatchId ) values (:bankruptID,:category,:lastname,:firstname,:patronymicname,:fullname,:inn,:snils,:ogrn,:region,:address,:birthdate,:birthplace,:guid,:uploadBatchId)
        """, rows[23:25])
            connection.commit()
```

Here are these two dictionaries:

```
[{'bankruptID': 140167, 'category': 'SimplePerson', 'lastname': 'ТЕСТОВА', 'firstname': 'ВАРВАРА', 'patronymicname': 'ПЕТРОВНА', 'fullname': 'ТЕСТОВА ВАРВАРА ПЕТРОВНА', 'inn': '', 'snils': '00000002207', 'ogrn': '', 'region': 'г. Москва', 'address': 'город Москва, улица Весенняя, дом 5 квартира 15', 'birthdate': datetime.datetime(1990, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'birthplace': 'город Москва', 'guid': '65398489B29F3A8B4B14928AFFC6CD91', 'uploadBatchId': '513013af-f80b-4c40-a5ed-54365caf12a7'}, 

{'bankruptID': 1490, 'category': 'SimpleOrganization', 'lastname': '', 'firstname': '', 'patronymicname': '', 'fullname': 'Закрытое акционерное общество "Залегощь-Сахар"', 'inn': '5709003233', 'snils': '', 'ogrn': '1025701655869', 'region': 'Орловская область', 'address': 'Орловская область, пгт. Залегощь, ул. М.Горького д. 87а', 'birthdate': '', 'birthplace': '', 'guid': '3D8707308FDA492A29E4E222534F210E', 'uploadBatchId': '513013af-f80b-4c40-a5ed-54365caf12a7'}]
```

If I use *executemany* with either of them separately (`[rows[23:24]]` or `[(rows[24:25]]`) the error is gone. Even if I use a loop where I go through every dictionary and upload them one by one using *execute* it's all fine and no error is reported.

I thought maybe it needed a list of tuples but it was also of no avail.

Comment: Are those _really_ dictionaries? The name *rows* suggests an extended type that may look like dicts. Please show how you call `send_data`. I am curious to know the origination of `rows`, helpful for a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A side comment: upgrade to the latest cx_Oracle, which is now called python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).